# Make a TextField use the minimum required width

Tags: forms, flutter

For a TextField to work in Flutter, you need to give it a length. I've got a form working by wrapping the TextFields in Expandeds but I'd rather have the TextField resize based on the required width so that as the user types, the TextField expands. Here's my form code:

```dart
return Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      initialValue: snapshot.data[0].toString(),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Width", labelStyle: ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      initialValue: snapshot.data[1].toString(),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Height"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
```

And here is a picture of my form:

[image: Form screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add horizontal padding to the TextField like this

```
  return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: List.generate(2,
            (index) => Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      initialValue: index == 0 ? "3280" : "2464",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: index == 0 ? "Width" : "Height"),
              ),
            ),
     ))),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set width for your text form field

for example:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 100,
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                initialValue: "11",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Width"),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 100,
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                initialValue: "22",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Height"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```